# How to write a query so that it runs in server without getting cancelled out on page refresh?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ajax, dapper

Say I have a webpage. In that webpage, I have a button with a click event listener. When I click on the button, it makes an ajax call(XMLHttpRequest) to update some values in server side database. My database query takes much time to complete and as a result, response also takes much time to come back to the client side(because the code is synchronous). And in the mean time, if I refresh my webpage, the ajax request gets cancelled and the update query also gets stopped.

I want to make it work in such a way that I will make the ajax call, and it will initiate the database query but it will not wait for it to complete. And even if, I refresh the page, the database query should not be cancelled out.

In the backend(server side), I have C# asp.net framework and sql server database.

So the ajax call goes to my server side code which is written in C# and from there I call a stored procedure that contains the long query.

I want that the ajax call will initiate this long query and will not wait for completion of the query. And even if I refresh the page, the query will not get cancelled out.(Ajax call may get cancelled out But the query 
 should not stop running in my server)

What are ways available in C#, dapper, asp.net and sql server to implement this scenario?

Comment: Not sure you can get AJAX to to do that.  But I hope someone knows a way.

Comment: If the query is taking a long time, perhaps the solution is not stopping the connection from being closed on refresh, but to improve the query so that it doesn't take so long to run. Just a thought. :)

Comment: As an addition to @Larnu's comment, if you think it might be improved upon but don't know how to approach it exactly, you might post your query on SO and ask for help, I'm sure some DB wizards will be able to help you. :)

Comment: The query is not my problem. Problem is that browser is cancelling it while page refresh. Otherwise , I can put my long  query in some asynchronous block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the query takes much time, you have a separate temp table for storing results from the query.

You create a stored procedure for the query and store the result from the query to the temp table with the username as a separate column.

You can initiate the stored procedure from the UI and you should be having a ajax method for retrieving the latest result from the temp table with respective to the particular user.

I hope you understood my explanation.

---

Updated:

Have a separate table for initiating the stored procedure. Now you can use sqldependency for running the stored procedure in the background for every onChange notification. Please view this answer for sqldependency implementation.

I hope this helps

Comment: But when I refresh the page, the query gets cancelled. The query takes time because It does a long calculation and then update some value, and I want this query to complete in my server side but it should not stop the response to go back to the client.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please refer this might be helpful

Comment: Ya, You are right. probably I need to use  service broker or sql depenency anyway. I was searching if there are any other options or not. Thanks.